# Replacing google maps to open street map

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, openstreetmap

I'm new to this. I'm creating an android application which locates my contacts. I have tried some tutorials and it runs. but how to replace google map to open street map. I have this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.PositionLocator.android">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon">
<activity android:name=".PositionLocator" android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>        
<activity android:name=".PositionLocatorMap" android:label="@string/app_name">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: So, what exactly is your problem/question?

Comment: @adinia how can I replace google map into openstreet map.

Answer (score 5):

The [mapsforge library](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/) seems also very promising. Seems that they are compatible to the GoogleMaps API and that you just need to exchange imports.

Answer (score 1):

Add below line:

```
compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.6.2'
```

into your build.gradle(Module:app) file's dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    //Other required dependencies
    compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.6.2'
}
```

This will include all required OSM libraries to your project.

In your xml file (map screen) replace below code with the already written Google maps code:

```
<!--<fragment-->
<!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
<!--android:layout_height="fill_parent"-->
<!--android:id="@+id/mapview"-->
<!--tools:context="MapActivity"-->
<!--android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"-->
<!--android:layout_below="@+id/header" />-->
<org.osmdroid.views.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layout_for_buttons"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Osmdroid works very well for this purpose:

http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/

We use it in our app and don't have any drawbacks until now.